# Not enough permissions to install service

Tags: service, wix, windows-installer

I have the following declaration of my service:

```
<ServiceControl Id="ServiceStartStop"
                Name="[name]"
                Start="install"
                Stop="both"
                Remove="both"
                Wait="no"/>
<ServiceInstall Id="ServiceRegister"
                Name="[name]"
                DisplayName="[displayname]"
                Description="[description]"
                Account="LocalSystem"
                Arguments="-start"
                ErrorControl="critical"
                Interactive="yes"
                Start="auto"
                Type="ownProcess"
                Vital="yes" >
  <util:PermissionEx  User="Authenticated Users"
                      ServiceChangeConfig = "yes"
                      ServiceEnumerateDependents = "yes"
                      ServiceInterrogate = "yes"
                      ServicePauseContinue = "yes"
                      ServiceQueryConfig = "yes"
                      ServiceQueryStatus = "yes"
                      ServiceStart = "yes"
                      ServiceStop = "yes"
                      ServiceUserDefinedControl = "yes" />
</ServiceInstall>
```

This compiles and links without any errors or warnings. The service `exe` is properly specified using `KeyPath="yes"`. When I run my msi, it can't get beyond at 'Starting Service...'. I get an error message, as follows:

[image]

The UAC is shown when I click 'Install', so what's going wrong?

Comment: Does your installer requires elevated permissions?

Comment: @KMoraz Yes, the service needs to be run with elevated privileges.

Comment: Did you set `<Package InstallPrivileges="elevated" />`?

Comment: @KMoraz I didn't, but that doesn't seem to have helped, I still get the same error dialog

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should work without the WiX util extension. Here is my complete test installer. Create your own test project and copy and past my installer into your .wxs file. Then replace the File, ServiceInstall and ServiceControl paths and names with your own service. If you still get the same error message, could it be that you don't actually have the privileges to do the install on your machine?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="TestServiceInstaller" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="test" UpgradeCode="d2b63c57-ca50-4f6a-8019-e826cac3d788">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="TestServiceInstaller" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="TestServiceInstaller" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="TestService.exe" Guid="196BB5E5-F157-4CA2-B740-0A68E1539B7C">
    <File Id="TestService.exe" Source="C:\Users\bryan.johnston\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestService\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
    <ServiceInstall Id="TestService.exe" Name="TestService.exe" Account="LocalSystem" Arguments="-start" Start="auto" Interactive="yes" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" ErrorControl="critical" />
    <ServiceControl Id="TestService.exe" Name="TestService.exe" Stop="both" Start="install" Remove="uninstall" Wait="no" />
  </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
    </Wix>
```

Comment: The problem for me was related to the fully qualified accout, as stated on @Chris Schiffhauer's answer.

Comment: This solved the issue for me without having to add the fully qualified account as discussed below.

Comment: InstallPrivileges is not allowed !

Answer (score 10):

The ServiceInstall Account must be fully qualified, as such:

`<ServiceInstall ... Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" />`

It can fail if only specified like this:

`<ServiceInstall ... Account="LocalService" />`

Comment: In this same vein, I had to change 
Account="MyCoolServiceAccount" 
to
Account=".\MyCoolServiceAccount" .

Comment: You've made my day!

Answer (score 4):

Probably you have to set the permission for the your service, something like that:

```
<ServiceInstall Id="YourServiceID" Name="ServiceName" DisplayName="DisplayName"
    Description="Description"   
 Arguments="service start arguments" 
 Start="demand" Type="ownProcess" ErrorControl="ignore">
    <util:PermissionEx User="Authenticated Users" 
ServiceStart="yes" 
ServiceStop="yes" 
ServicePauseContinue="yes" 
ServiceInterrogate="yes" 
ServiceChangeConfig="yes" 
ServiceEnumerateDependents="yes" 
ServiceQueryConfig="yes" 
ServiceQueryStatus="yes" 
ServiceUserDefinedControl="yes" />
</ServiceInstall>
<ServiceControl Id="SvcControlID" Name="ServiceName" Stop="both" 
    Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
```

and dont forget to include the UtilExtension:
    xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"

There is another way (but not recomended :)
You could try to install it using custom actions:

```
<Property Id="CMD" Secure="yes"><![CDATA[cmd.exe]]></Property>
<CustomAction Id="InstallService32" Property="CMD" ExeCommand="/c &quot;&quot;[INSTALLLOCATION][ServiceName]&quot; /i [ServiceName] &quot;/c [SVC_CONFIG]&quot;&quot;" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="ignore" />
<CustomAction Id="InstallService64" Property="CMD" ExeCommand="/c &quot;&quot;[INSTALLLOCATION][ServiceName]&quot; /i [ServiceName] &quot;/c [SVC_CONFIG]&quot;&quot;" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="ignore" />    
<CustomAction Id="StartService" Property="CMD" ExeCommand="/c &quot;NET START [ServiceName]&quot;" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="ignore" />
<CustomAction Id="StopService" Property="CMD" ExeCommand="/c &quot;NET STOP [ServiceName]&quot;" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="ignore" />
```

The problem with this code is that you need to have the install location without the white spaces (I had a problem with white spaces and could not manage to solve it, probably you'll be more lucky).

Comment: How do I include the UtilExtension?

Comment: go to the tab "Tools Settings" in your wix project properties and add the next line to the Addition Parameters (for the Compiler and Linker):  -ext WixUtilExtension.

Comment: also under Wix tag (where your service defined) you should have something like this: <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"> to add a schema definition for utils

Comment: I'm doing this on the command line, I just needed to add `-ext WixUtilExtension`.

Comment: Ok, even after adding that section I still get the same error.

Comment: Probably you need to add more permissions to your service. You could find more information at http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_permissionex.htm

Comment: I've added all the Service permissions - still getting the same error. I've updated the question to make it a bit clearer what's going on

Comment: Does your service require to do addition activities?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. Interestingly, *removing* the `PermissionsEx` section will allow the service to install, but not start.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, it was caused by an earlier version of the service still running on the system.  To fix this launch an elevated command line prompt and type:

```
 SC delete NameOfService
```

Comment: An alternative is "installutil /u NameOfService.exe".

Answer (score 2):

The error message is misleading. You will get that error message whenever the service fails to start, but it may not have anything to do with permissions.

1. Open a visual studio command prompt and manually install it:

   ```
   installutil <name_of_service.exe>
   ```
2. Then try manually starting the service on your machine (via services.msc).

If your service fails, it is an issue with your service and not the installer.

Answer (score 1):

This can also occur when the services file name (in my case an .exe) is wrong. I managed to work aroud by putting the correct file (the executable) to the first place in the file list sth like:

The name of the service file name can be viewed in the Event viewer - Event Id of service installation is 7045

Regards 
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Yet another reason while this common error will be thrown:

If there is an invalid `ServiceConfig` element below the `ServiceInstall` element.

Most probably this will apply to any invalid child element of `ServiceInstall`.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of failed attempts, in my case all goes well after removing `Account="LocalSystem"` in the *ServiceInstall* tag (by default Windows install the service as *LocalSystem*)