# Wix installer: Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services

Tags: wcf, service, wix, installation

I'm using Wix installer. When I run installer I get this error:

[image]

I'm logged as administrator. I also tried create anotherone user.
So I tried:

1| I add my user "Administrator" to place "Log on as a service"

[image]

2| I checked my Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service if is running

[image]

3| I get my SID

[image]

4| I added to SMSvcHost.exe.config section  with my SID.

Check "My administrator sid"

```
<system.serviceModel.activation>
   <net.tcp listenBacklog="10" maxPendingConnections="100" maxPendingAccepts="2" receiveTimeout="00:00:10" teredoEnabled="false">
      <allowAccounts>
         // My administrator sid
         <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-21-334175509-2570308825-1313804348-500"/>

          // LocalSystem account
          <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-18"/>

          // LocalService account
          <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-19"/>

          // Administrators account
          <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-20"/>

          // Network Service account
          <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-32-544" />

          // IIS_IUSRS account (Vista only)
           <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-32-568"/>
      </allowAccounts>
   </net.tcp>
   <net.pipe maxPendingConnections="100" maxPendingAccepts="2" receiveTimeout="00:00:10">
      <allowAccounts>
          // LocalSystem account
          <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-18"/>

          // LocalService account
          <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-19"/>

          // Administrators account
          <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-20"/>

          // Network Service account
          <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-32-544" />

          // IIS_IUSRS account (Vista only)
          <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-32-568"/>
      </allowAccounts>
   </net.pipe>
   <diagnostics performanceCountersEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel.activation>
```

5| I edit all SMSvcHost.exe.config for sure:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

6| Restart = Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service

7| When I got that warning message during instalation, I didn't cancel, I tried also run service from path where files are installed and via cmd prompt I run manualy and it's run.

[image]

8| But my instalator can't finish instalation. Everytime I got that sentense: "Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services." I can only cancel instalation and instalation roll back and delete all files.

ANY HELP PLEASE? 5 DAYS I'M GOING AROUND THIS WITHOUT RESULT. I TESTED THAT ON 2 DIFERRENT VIRTUAL MACHINES WITH WINDOWS SERVER X64 AND WINDOWS 8 X64.

My component code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3.6\bin\heat.exe" dir ..\WindowsServiceHost\bin\Release -dr TARGETDIR -cg WindowsServiceHost_Project -scom -sfrag -sreg -srd -gg -var var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir -out WindowsServiceHost.wxs -pog Binaries -pog Content
-->
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <!-- The initially, this has been created with Heat to get all output -->
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
            <Component Id="cmpF563E3CE297225623330C6BDFBFCDB12" Guid="{6742348C-A620-46FA-8DA8-0EB0CCA1C123}">
                <File Id="fil21CA92101BF52AFED2FDCE521FCA6123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp353671C776668DEF5DCC15C233E2CA49" Guid="{A8F26FCD-4BBB-4665-903A-45DDAAFE3123}">
                <File Id="fil889A0DB56C827E66FA3035CED6E3E123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Castle.ActiveRecord.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpCD33B68B2028B11161C5509206174D37" Guid="{248DAA3F-EC3C-44E5-A57A-DD7090222123}">
                <File Id="fil98E1300420674E5F83417696A895A123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Castle.Components.Validator.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp4AE2CD167FF4894E9076AF5FC612D123" Guid="{D7BB86D2-A384-4AAE-8D52-B0877B849123}">
                <File Id="fil808D19806529ABA1617D818072819123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Castle.Core.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpD9F8C495CF8479B78BC318E8E9DAA123" Guid="{DA1C4B1F-FE3C-42D2-A273-39BFB2FB7123}">
                <File Id="fil2EBE8BAEA1EB66844366CCC4FD863123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp3F6A205A397BEA19BBA40D18483BD123" Guid="{2FDB99B1-D558-4750-A3DB-00D8EB1C1123}">
                <File Id="fil151C8FBAEDA5D4BDEB438F301EAE7123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Castle.Windsor.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpC070BF8C300741A523BD7ED7CBB9C123" Guid="{71DDC933-8912-4CEB-9257-FE07A0A3C123}">
                <File Id="filD577F4DF6A5A8E2CC82379AC96025123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Viewer.Viewer.DAL.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp38F30287B63682CF5E25FFED1C597123" Guid="{896B54CA-6279-48A2-A20D-6C32D9370123}">
                <File Id="fil2E5F30135D3485052620C0369A0C8123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Viewer.Viewer.exe" />

                <!-- This is the problem I was having - I was not able to reference this component and this is not supported yes as based on hours of googling -->
                <!-- We're able to define almost anything on how the service is configured, under which user, etc -->
                <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Name="ViewerService"
                              DisplayName="Viewer Service" Description="Viewer service handles all user requests and manages tasks."
                              Start="auto" Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]" Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]" ErrorControl="ignore" Interactive="no">
                  <util:ServiceConfig FirstFailureActionType="restart"  SecondFailureActionType="restart" ThirdFailureActionType="restart" />
                </ServiceInstall>
                <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="ViewerService" Wait="yes" />

            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpF4715A23C1FF23A034E3C5D7E9899123" Guid="{5439277D-DA70-476D-AFA3-A7E21792B123}">
                <File Id="filD6D2807DE16A409F1A2667BA03ED8123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Viewer.exe.config" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpED6174C35AEBF8A8918AC859C9681123" Guid="{84A5A3C2-A5DE-40AB-8ADC-31D2A5C1E123}">
                <File Id="fil5DD49061C2ED546B40CEED5FC1BD2123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Viewer.Library.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpB2A2EA83D72F4C7290397730910A4123" Guid="{6A8F8C8A-47E7-4A70-B05C-92EA6711B123}">
                <File Id="filF3891F073E13532E343276EC37F96123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\PstLibrary.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpEBE3708427CCDA04E12DE366A56F4123" Guid="{60645E54-C07B-41B3-B219-4B7CECC5A123}">
                <File Id="fil06760C8D25183C8A8CF53F339D6BC123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Iesi.Collections.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp2B6E39BC25CC0CDCEC3DAC9E80C14123" Guid="{6728EDE3-FCCD-4FC1-9032-2EA6F84E7123}">
                <File Id="fil3CA8B6115A016E51F3BA10386CAEE123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp95FFFFB1FF4FE88C7ABFAFDC94AFA123" Guid="{354B5354-4134-4225-9FA8-B6EBD1566123}">
                <File Id="filD2AD4A87E4FFD97570BD414BF64D2123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\LogModule.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp06CFD0EF8C78731C8FE99058BA827123" Guid="{13D3CCD4-A068-40F7-91F7-01BD9DAC7123}">
                <File Id="filC52F7EC41731AA5B6D39C500DF546123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Lucene.Net.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp02134B521CDB778B256053B705B39123" Guid="{AB850CDB-C591-47C4-876A-00744AFAC123}">
                <File Id="fil8B09A9C2BC8D71A0E5E923F6F4039123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\MailBee.NET.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp0732D020141A27B3EF606680AF63C123" Guid="{39446EE7-47AE-4757-B5A4-DED57F7CE123}">
              <File Id="fil194D74862CE83A0371D6324FE1C0D123" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\_dependencies\Interop.Redemption.dll" />
            </Component>         
            <Component Id="cmp0732D020141A27B3EF606680AF632123" Guid="{39446EE7-47AE-4757-B5A4-DED57F7C2123}">
              <File Id="fil194D74862CE83A0371D6324FE1C02123" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\_dependencies\Redemption64.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp9D56D720C5BABC0701758947084E5123" Guid="{E5C9921B-AA90-4B88-898F-5A3C6D2F7123}">
                <File Id="filFEE1876E7EF6CE4F720645154DFD8123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp48A389F21271FDC5825A9C1B25E82123" Guid="{D485D984-1568-4A28-B2EC-EFE9791B7123}">
                <File Id="fil6EDFA9A322A7AB6A8E262D0DB4F60123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\NHibernate.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpFEBBE1308148FADB702D2C8F4D13E123" Guid="{725DD9FB-61EC-48F8-A988-916C30C73123}">
                <File Id="fil5145831B362C7509226E3A90E8FF2123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\NHibernate.Search.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpEED54193D815302FC314DB0A2C9F8123" Guid="{DD277B4A-63F4-4988-BA83-D9AF1FC89123}">
                <File Id="filF81E55DF73063A3872976B67B6628123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Library.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpA42846C9FB9AE5A84F07BCD1C1077123" Guid="{7A89E8A4-D5DC-4EB2-A80B-BB3455B2F123}">
              <File Id="fil10DFB7AB70BD839083EA5F5DCA22C123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Processing.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpE88CBB7A43EF8781FD98762843CF1123" Guid="{862E6578-5507-4128-89CA-877315A88123}">
              <File Id="fil6095C78A39C6633B24FADCC044720123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\RedemptionWrapper.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp74BE405C599A7B2BFF4B24B035404123" Guid="{65632DE4-45A3-4C81-911F-8E0EA7073123}">
                <File Id="fil9FAD52E634F2925DB072CBBAE8AC5123" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)\Remotion.Data.Linq.dll" />
            </Component>
            <Directory Id="dirD9D25461613D53ECC73127337CA03123" Name="Licenses">
                <Component Id="cmpC47DFFE5D48426458E24BE6D0A83C123" Guid="{4F3CFB3D-4E7A-4430-8EC6-3403EB856123}">
                    <File Id="filF3CFC81B4D04F6521220038AE4103123" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\Common\Licenses\Antlr3.license.txt" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp322E81F6D6B5D7FFE823EAEABAE77123" Guid="{E48BC22E-682C-4D87-BABF-1E71F6AE2123}">
                    <File Id="fil7294E69E9C2DDF5F09B62BA6E2EB1123" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\Common\Licenses\Castle.license.txt" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp5537750B07AA6621D099EA533E58C123" Guid="{412C1F3B-1A6C-444F-8645-4503F484F123}">
                    <File Id="filFFF3C0457CC60E6EC076FBB3DD232123" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\Common\Licenses\Iesi.Collections.license.txt" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp92EF42C91FD5F2D0797844A57BE78123" Guid="{E35E3446-8DD2-4DE0-B7FE-E27556D8D123}">
                    <File Id="filA9F4D112BA2C37F6067E328E8C972123" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\Common\Licenses\Ionic.Zip.license.txt" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpD6E1D6312AA116069E68B968F9AED123" Guid="{B670C6F0-901F-4049-A256-406B77F0E123}">
                    <File Id="filC50888C92A23713C5CE5FA816A8F9123" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\Common\Licenses\Lucene.Net.license.txt" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp1EEBF5BABE23C2C767438072E6410123" Guid="{3799AA4F-A169-41A1-A1DE-907F315E3123}">
                    <File Id="filE39771746641899F88B2A3B05E9AA123" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\Common\Licenses\NHibernate.license.txt" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpCF5ECE8D2EADADA313278BA15AF99123" Guid="{94C3D676-8B2B-4AAE-A4BC-226763BEE123}">
                    <File Id="filC1AA47E8984A0651CDA4689D2A768123" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\Common\Licenses\NLog.license.txt" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp599BAD3717C0FCEE410496C8E8066123" Guid="{CF247694-83FE-456D-8645-55EDF88AD123}">
                    <File Id="filF046615251B088B6CBFB5383F775F123" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\Common\Licenses\Remotion.Data.Linq.license.txt" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="WindowsServiceHost_Project">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpF563E3CE297225623330C6BDFBFCD123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp353671C776668DEF5DCC15C233E2C123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpCD33B68B2028B11161C5509206174123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp4AE2CD167FF4894E9076AF5FC612D123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpD9F8C495CF8479B78BC318E8E9DAA123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp3F6A205A397BEA19BBA40D18483BD123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpC070BF8C300741A523BD7ED7CBB9C123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp38F30287B63682CF5E25FFED1C597123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpF4715A23C1FF23A034E3C5D7E9899123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpED6174C35AEBF8A8918AC859C9681123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpB2A2EA83D72F4C7290397730910A4123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpEBE3708427CCDA04E12DE366A56F4123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp2B6E39BC25CC0CDCEC3DAC9E80C14123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp95FFFFB1FF4FE88C7ABFAFDC94AFA123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp06CFD0EF8C78731C8FE99058BA827123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp02134B521CDB778B256053B705B39123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp9D56D720C5BABC0701758947084E5123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp48A389F21271FDC5825A9C1B25E82123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpFEBBE1308148FADB702D2C8F4D13E123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpEED54193D815302FC314DB0A2C9F8123" />            
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp74BE405C599A7B2BFF4B24B035404123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpC47DFFE5D48426458E24BE6D0A83C123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp322E81F6D6B5D7FFE823EAEABAE77123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp5537750B07AA6621D099EA533E58C123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp92EF42C91FD5F2D0797844A57BE78123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpD6E1D6312AA116069E68B968F9AED123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp1EEBF5BABE23C2C767438072E6410123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpCF5ECE8D2EADADA313278BA15AF99123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp599BAD3717C0FCEE410496C8E8066123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp0732D020141A27B3EF606680AF63C123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpA42846C9FB9AE5A84F07BCD1C1077123" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpE88CBB7A43EF8781FD98762843CF1123" />            
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp0732D020141A27B3EF606680AF632123" />          
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Can you post your component code used to install the services?

Comment: I edit my post with component code above. Thank you.

Comment: The error is misleading. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588002/not-enough-permissions-to-install-service/9669831#9669831

Comment: Probably I have problem with Build Definition on TFS, because if I'll build installer and grab from folder and transfer to virtual machine it pass. But when I create new build, installator get stack with starting service. Oh my god that's gonna be other challange :) Anyway thank you.

Comment: any luck? if yes please share the location

Answer (score 4):

Just fix the same problem by seperating the service control. Do this

```
<ServiceControl Id="scStorageServiceReporter_Start"
    Name="Dhcp"
    Start="install"
    Wait="no" />

<ServiceControl Id="scStorageServiceReporter_Stop"
    Name="Dhcp"
    Stop="uninstall"
    Remove="uninstall"
    Wait="yes" />
```

instead of this

```
<ServiceControl
    Id="scStorageReporter"
    Name="StorageReporterService"
    Start="install"
    Stop="both"
    Remove="uninstall"
    Wait="yes"/>
```

Comment: This got an upvote from me.  While it didn't solve the issue completely, it allowed me to see what the actual problem was (I forgot to copy a config file) via the Windows Event Viewer.

Comment: @MikeAtkisson omg thank you. I spent hours trying to figure out the error message in the OP only to discover, after reading your comment, in the event viewer that it is actually because of a missing frame work. Bizarre error message mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your snippet this may be a red herring, but I've seen this exact same error if your installer is also adding items to the GAC (which yours doesn't seem to be - hence the red herring). This is due to GAC'd components not being available until *after* the service control attempts to start the service. In this case the "permissions" message isn't accurate either!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rebuild the wix project. I got this issue too and rebuilding the project has fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case the problem was that the configuration `*.config` file that is used by my windows service was invalid, because of that the service could not be started. It took me a while to figure out what the problem was.
Maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error also because the application that starts running is throwing an exception soon after start. For example I got this error because I had Console.ReadKey in my code.

The best way to check if this is the case is to check your application logs. By default Windows Event Viewer won't have any helpful information.