# Run a command and see its output

Tags: windows, shell, terminal, service, windows-installer

I am invoking `sc.exe` from my installer:

```
[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /c sc create ...
```

to start a Windows service, but all I know is that the service does not start.

What can I use instead of `cmd.exe` in order to see the output of the `sc` command (and the command itself, if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

What type of installer is this? MSI installers should use the [**`ServiceInstall`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/serviceinstall-table) and [**`ServiceControl`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/servicecontrol-table) tables to install and control a service binary. This is all "automagic" and works very reliably if you follow the correct procedure. **There is no need to use a custom action to install a Windows Service with MSI**.

***WiX***: If you are using WiX, here are some resources to help you install services:

- [Rainer Stropek's Windows Service WiX Sample](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples/WindowsService)
- [Chris Painter's IsWiX service installation sample](https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials/tree/master/windows-service)
- https://github.com/Robs79/How-to-create-a-Windows-Service-MSI-Installer-Using-WiX

---

***Advanced Installer***: If you are not using WiX, here is a section on Advanced Installer and service installation:

- https://www.advancedinstaller.com/installing-windows-services.html
- https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-install-service.html

---

***Service Launch Failure Debugging***: If you have problems starting the service at all (even without an installer - for example on a clean virtual), please review the below check lists for potential problems ([the most common startup problems](https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912487-Debug-service-start-failures-) are usually: `missing runtimes`, `permission problems`, `missing files`, `bitness problems x86 64`, `error in configuration files`, `etc...` [old answer on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68762945/129130)):

- [Desktop applicaton not opening after installation in client system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512998/desktop-applicaton-not-opening-after-installation-in-client-system/53530377#53530377)
- [Windows Application Startup Error Exception code: 0xe0434352](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623588/windows-application-startup-error-exception-code-0xe0434352/49637913#49637913)

---

***Further Links:***

- [Helge Klein full installer sample for WiX](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2014/09/real-world-example-wix-msi-application-installer/) (search for ServiceInstall)
- [Lots of WiX Quick Start Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)

Comment: I create an MSI using WiX. I need to use `sc.exe`, because I do not have a binary specifically suited for usage as a Windows service. As far as I understand, I need *both* to install a service using `ServiceInstall`&`ServiceControl` and to manually create and start it using `sc.exe`.

Comment: What are you using to make the binary run as a service? I don't use this kind of stuff, but I know about [Srvany](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSrvany). I know there are [several common Srvany problems](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/srvany/top-3-srvany-problems/) and I believe the tool has not been updated in a long time (I didn't check recently). If this is your own binary I would seriously consider making it a proper service.

Comment: I am not familiar with [AlwaysUp](https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/) either. Here is [a list of further Srvany problems](https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/srvany.html).

Comment: And in my notes I found [TopShelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf). Never tried it. Perhaps you use it already? Github project is set read-only.  (*"Topshelf is a framework for hosting services written using the .NET framework. The creation of services is simplified, allowing developers to create a simple console application that can be installed as a service using Topshelf. The reason for this is simple: It is far easier to debug a console application than a service."*)